# Reliably determine the size of char

Tags: c++, c, sizeof

I was wondering how to reliably determine the size of a character in a portable way. AFAIK sizeof(char) can not be used because this yields always 1, even on system where the byte has 16 bit or even more or less.

For example when dealing with bits, where you need to know exactly how big it is, I was wondering if this code would give the real size of a character, independent on what the compiler thinks of it. IMO the pointer has to be increased by the compiler to the correct size, so we should have the correct value. Am I right on this, or might there be some hidden problem with pointer arithmetics, that would yield also wrong results on some systems?

```
int sizeOfChar()
{
    char *p = 0;
    p++;
    int size_of_char = (int)p;
    return size_of_char;
}
```

Comment: `CHAR_BIT` or `CHAR_MAX` are the simple portable methods.

Comment: there is a `sizeof` operator too, Just FYI `sizeof(char)`

Comment: sizeof is not always useful, because there are cases where you need to know wether a char is 8 Bit or something else. Sizeof doesn't provide this information.

Comment: @abasu `sizeof(char) == 1` **by definition**. Even if (on some machine) a `char` can hold more than one byte. I know, it's strange.

Comment: @leemes, yes, that was why I was wondering how to reliably get the information of number of bits, and came up with my code. :) Well, I discarded it now and uses the definition from limits.h. I never understood why the standard didn't add at least datatypes with a fixed with of bits for the cases where you need it.

Comment: @Devolus I know as you write it in your question; the comment was in response to abasu's comment, because he suggested to use `sizeof(char)`. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's not clear what you consider to be "right" (or "reliable", as in the title).

Do you consider "a byte is 8 bits" to be the right answer? If so, for a platform where `CHAR_BIT` is 16, then you would of course get your answer by just computing:

```
const int octets_per_char = CHAR_BIT / 8;
```

No need to do pointer trickery. Also, the trickery is tricky:

On an architecture with 16 bits as the smallest addressable piece of memory, there would be 16 bits at address 0x0000<sup>1</sup>, *another* 16 bits at address 0x0001, and so on.

So, your example would compute the result 1, since the pointer would likely be incremented from 0x0000 to 0x0001, but that doesn't seem to be what you expect it to compute.

<sup>1</sup> I use a 16-bit address space for brevity, it makes the addresses easier to read.

Comment: Actually this is exactly what I wanted to know. I would expect that the memory adresses are always in chunks of 8 bit, but of course this assumption might be wrong for some systems, thus my question. I know that there are some old machines which have 12 bits or others, so on such systems the pointer arithmetic would probably also wrong.

Comment: Memory addresses are what define `CHAR_BIT` and the actual size of a char, not the other way round. A char is the unit of data that fits into one "address slot".

Answer (score 7):

There's a `CHAR_BIT` macro defined in `<limits.h>` that evaluates to exactly what its name suggests.

---

> IMO the pointer has to be increased by the compiler to the correct size, so we should have the correct value

No, because pointer arithmetic is defined in terms of `sizeof(T)` (the pointer target type), and the `sizeof` operator yields the size in bytes. `char` is always exactly one byte long, so your code will always yield the `NULL` pointer plus one (which may not be the numerical value `1`, since `NULL` is not required to be 0).

Comment: That's god to know as I didn't know about it, but it doesn't answer my question wether this code would reliably return the correct result independent of any definition.

Comment: Yes, my code of course. I assume that the system macro should be valid. :)

Comment: @Devolus your code would most likely return 1 regardless of the number of bits in a char.

Comment: @Devolus Updated. It won't.

Answer (score 2):

The size of one char (aka byte ) in bits is determined by the macro `CHAR_BIT` in `<limits.h>` (or `<climits>` in C++).
The `sizeof` operator always returns the size of a type in bytes, not in bits.

So if on some system `CHAR_BIT` is 16 and `sizeof(int)` is 4, that means an int has 64 bits on that system.